# jQuery .prop("disabled",true) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown that loads the data and there is a `Add` button and when the add button is being triggered it will be disabled. It works in the first load, but when the dropdown is `onchange` the `disabled` button will be `false` or not disabled. So how can I still disable the button when the dropdown is being changed. I have also a `input field` to store the values of the button that has been clicked. Check http://jsfiddle.net/leonardeveloper/qy9u5/.

Comment: `.prop("disabled", true);` is working perfectly fine, but your appending a **brand new** element every time the drop-down is changed.

Comment: so was i, i tried determining it base on the input field values where the id is equal to the value of the button. i try .split() function to get the id and compare it to the value of the button and call the `"disabled",true`but still does not work.\

Comment: Even if an element has the same `id` as a previously seen element, it is still a different element in the browser's eyes. Create all the tables and show/hide them accordingly, or make a record of the numbers that have been used. See my answer.

Comment: yes it works perfectly. i hope that would fix my problem if i integrated it in my project. cause i just created it with the same logic. well then thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, you are appending a new element every time your `<select>` is changed. You need to be showing and hiding the same respective table each time. You can use jQuery to create those tables using the `<option>`s. Like so:

```
$("#loads option").each(function(){
    thisNumber = this.value;
    $("#displays").append("<table data-table="+thisNumber+"><tr><td>"+thisNumber+"</td><td>"+thisNumber+"</td><td><button class='materialId' value='"+thisNumber+"'>Add</button></td></tr></table>");
    $("#displays table").hide();
});
```

We append the tables (2 in this case) to `#displays`, and then hide them. When we change the `<select>` now, we hide all tables, and show the one we selected, I've used `data-table` for this but there are many ways to target your specific table.

```
$(document).on("change","#loads", function(){
    $("#displays table").hide();
    $("#displays table[data-table="+this.value+"]").show();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qy9u5/4/)

Comment: what is the `[data-table="+this.value+"]"`?

Comment: You [can use `[]` in selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select matching attributes (`data-table` is the attribute here). And this.value is quite self-explanitory, it's the current element's value, if applicable.

Comment: can i add you in facebook mate? i really want you to show what i'm working with.

Comment: If you have another question then ask it on here, otherwise we can use the site's chat.

Comment: i really don't know how to explain it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35448/discussion-between-f4r-20-and-leonard-drapeza)

Comment: SO Automatically moved this conversation: try http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35448/discussion-between-f4r-20-and-leonard-drapeza

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind click event also.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qy9u5/2/)

```
$(document).on("change click","#loads",...
```

Comment: still not working. i want the `Add`button of the id's that has been stored in the input field will be disabled